# How to use Symfony Web Profiler from a separate container?

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

My application is split into 2 Docker containers: Frontend app (only static content, HTML, CSS, JS) and backend API (Symfony application). So the browser loads frontend app (`http://localhost:8030`) which then makes requests to the API on a different host/container (`http://localhost:8031`).

How can I use Symfony Web Profiler toolbar with this setup?

Normally Symfony injects HTML for the toolbar into each returned HTML response. But in my case Symfony never returns any HTML and acts only as the API for Json data.
I can see all requests in the profiler by going to `http://localhost:8031/_profiler/search`, but I'd like to have the full toolbar in the frontend app loaded through `http://localhost:8030`.

Is it possible to somehow manually inject profiler HTML code into responses returned *not* by Symfony application?

Comment: Profiler hooks into events, and I think you'd need to jump through a lot of hoops to get this to work. You'd basically have to serialize the HTML, CSS and JS that it uses to JSON and include it in every response, and I'm really not certain how you'd do that. Although not the same, you could look for the `X-Debug-Token-Link` in the API response which should at least give you the link to the current profiler, and you could expose that in your front-facing app.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm thinking about now: to build myself a small part of debug toolbar and build AJAX requests table, like in the original toolbar, from AJAX responses headers.